# Extract rows from file_1 based on matching the first two columns from a file_2

Tags: awk, grep

File_1

```
##chr   pos rc  allele_count    allele_states   deletion_sum    snp_type    most_variable_allele    diff:1-2    diff:1-3    diff:1-4    diff:1-5    diff:1-6    diff:1-7    diff:1-8    diff:1-9    diff:1-10   diff:1-11   diff:1-12   diff:2-3
MT  227 C   2   C/A 0   pop C   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.024   0   0.022   0   0   0
MT  233 G   2   G/T 0   pop G   0   0.009   0   0.012   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.009
MT  245 G   2   G/A 0   pop A   0   0   0   0   0   0.055   0.224   0.072   0.026   0   0   0
MT  251 C   2   C/T 0   pop C   0.276   0.034   0.231   0.005   0.027   0.036   0.025   0.002   0.107   0.034   0.034   0.309
MT  264 G   2   G/C 0   pop G   0   0   0   0.008   0   0.003   0   0   0   0   0   0
MT  286 G   2   G/T 0   pop T   0.002   0.002   0.002   0.002   0.002   0.002   0.002   0.002   0.002   0   0.002   0
MT  292 A   2   A/T 0   pop T   0   0   0   0   0.003   0   0   0.002   0   0   0   0
MT  293 G   2   G/T 0   pop G   0   0   0   0   0.003   0.002   0   0   0   0   0   0
MT  295 G   2   G/T 0   pop G   0   0.002   0.002   0   0.001   0.002   0.002   0.002   0.002   0.002   0.002   0.003
```

File_2

```
MT  251
MT  292
MT  295
```

desired_output

```
##chr   pos rc  allele_count    allele_states   deletion_sum    snp_type    most_variable_allele    diff:1-2    diff:1-3    diff:1-4    diff:1-5    diff:1-6    diff:1-7    diff:1-8    diff:1-9    diff:1-10   diff:1-11   diff:1-12   diff:2-3
MT  251 C   2   C/T 0   pop C   0.276   0.034   0.231   0.005   0.027   0.036   0.025   0.002   0.107   0.034   0.034   0.309
MT  292 A   2   A/T 0   pop T   0   0   0   0   0.003   0   0   0.002   0   0   0   0
MT  295 G   2   G/T 0   pop G   0   0.002   0.002   0   0.001   0.002   0.002   0.002   0.002   0.002   0.002   0.003
```

It's similar to what was wanted in this post:[Compare two files by first column. Keep rows if matching](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450427/compare-two-files-by-first-column-keep-rows-if-matching)

I was using `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=$0;next}a[$0]'` for keeping overlap with first column, but I need the entire row when they match the first two columns (chr and pos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just test whether the first two columns are keys of the array, instead of testing the entire line with `$0`.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1" "$2] = 1; next}
     FNR == 1 && FNR != NR {print} # print header
     $1" "$2 in a' File_2 File_1
```

Comment: Thanks! the column headers weren't added to the output, but that's trivial to do.