# extract all rows from file_1 except those with first two columns matching the first two columns from file_2

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I would like to do the inverse of this (exactly same example): 
[Extract rows from file_1 based on matching the first two columns from a file_2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491395/extract-rows-from-file-1-based-on-matching-the-first-two-columns-from-a-file-2/491396#491396)

That is, extract all rows from file_1 except those with the first two columns matching the first two columns from file_2.

Answer:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {get[$1" "$2]++; next} !get[$1" "$2]' f2.txt f1.txt
```

Comment: You can use the logical negation of the previous condition: `!($1" "$2 in a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {get[$1" "$2]++; next} !get[$1" "$2]' f1.txt f2.txt
```